# How to change all directory and file in repository?

Tags: git

I have some folder an some file in repository, and now I want to change all directory and file. How to change all directory and file in repository? Help me

Answer (score 0):

Git can internally detect a file or folder which is moved to another directory as a change, in the same way it can detect a modification to a single file.  So all you have to do is move the files and folders, and then commit this change:

```
$ mv /user/orignal/* /user/new
$ cd /user/original
$ git add -a
$ git commit -m 'Moved all files and folders from original to new directory'
```

The above move (`mv`) command would move everything (files and folders) under `/user/orignal` to the directory `/user/new`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the files and directories at your will. `git status` will tell you what to do then:
`git add $filename` to add the new ones
`git rm $filename` to remove the old names
Then commit and push.

Git will recognize if files/directories were just moved/renamed.

Comment: Can you give the reason for downvoting?

Comment: I'm guessing it was either a moderator in a rush, or an ill-intending user.  Our answers are both basically right and should not (IMO) be getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have unversioned files in your directory, you can use

```
$ git add -A
```

after you renamed your files and directories.

This adds all untracked and changed files in your repository to your git history.

Folders are only tracked if they have versioned content.

And of course, commit (and push if necessary) your changes.

```
$ git commit -m "commit message"
$ git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want, so I can only guess. You want to actually get the files and edit them? Then you need to clone the repository first and then edit them.

```
git clone http://yourrepo.com/someproject.git folderForProject
```

Then you have all your files locally and can edit them however you like. At the end you have to commit and push them (if you want them back in the repo).

```
git commit -am "Edited something"
git push
```